# iterating through every instance of xml tag

Tags: xml, powershell, scripting

I'm new to Powershell and I'm trying to read in an XML document and then for every Node that's called `<document>` I want to look inside it.

Not too sure how to do this in powershell. At the moment, I'm only looking at the first instance called `<document>` and then inside that. But a file could have multiple nodes called `<document>` such as the example one.

How can I get an instance of every node called document and then `foreach` through them? Ideally I'd like a list of nodes called `document` returned and then I can iterate over them.

```
<List state='null'>
    <document>
        <i_state>null</i_state>
        <i_toronto>qwe</i_toronto>
        <i_site>123</i_site>
        <i_library>potluck</i_library>
        <i_url>www.google.com</i_url>
        <mmdete>
            <metafy>Oblong</metafy>
        </mmdete>
       </document>
    <document>
        <i_state>null</i_state>
        <i_toronto>qwe</i_toronto>
        <i_site>123</i_site>
        <i_lib>potluck</i_lib>
        <i_url>https:www.google.com</i_url>
        <mmdete>
            <metafy>Oblong</metafy>
        </mmdete>
       </document>

</List>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `SelectNodes('//nodename')`:

```
$XmlFile = [xml](Get-Content .\file.xml)
$XmlFile.SelectNodes('//document') |ForEach-Object {
    $_ # this now refers to a "document" XmlNode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell works just fine with XML, so long as it knows that is what it's looking at. If you make your variable the `[XML]` type, you can reference those document nodes fairly easily through a number of methods. For instance, I saved your sample as 'testdata.txt' and did the following:

```
[xml]$source = get-content testdata.txt
$source.list.document
```

PowerShell returned the following:

```
i_state   : null
i_toronto : qwe
i_site    : 123
i_library : potluck
i_url     : www.google.com
mmdete    : mmdete

i_state   : null
i_toronto : qwe
i_site    : 123
i_lib     : potluck
i_url     : https:www.google.com
mmdete    : mmdete
```

If you do not know where the node will be you can use the `Select-XML` cmdlet to search by xpath for your nodes.

```
$source|select-xml -XPath '//document'|select -expand node
```

That will provide the same output.